# Extract Date and Currency value(separated by comma) from file

Tags: python, regex, file-io

**Objective:**

Extract String data, Currency value , [type of currency] and date.

**Content of file:**

> `[["1234567890","Your previous month subscription point is <RS|$|QR|#> 5,200.33.Your current month month subscription point is <RS|$|QR|#> 1,15,200.33, Last Year total point earned <RS|$|QR|#> 5589965.26 and point lost in game is <RS|$|QR|#> 11520 your this year subscription will expire on 19-04-2013. 9. Back"],["1234567890","Your previous month subscription point is <RS|$|QR|#> 5,200.33.Your current month month subscription point is <RS|$|QR|#> 1,15,200.33, Last Year total point earned <RS|$|QR|#> 5589965.26 and point lost in game is <RS|$|QR|#> 11520 your this year subscription will expire on 19-04-2013. 9. Back"]]`

**What I have done so far:**

```
def read_file():
        fp = open('D:\\ReadData2.txt', 'rb')
        content = fp.read()
        data = eval(content)  
        l1 = ["%s" % x[1] for x in data]
        return l1

    def check_currency(l2):
        import re
        for i in range(l2.__len__()):
            newstr2  = l2[i]
            val_currency = []
            val_currency.extend(re.findall(r'([+-]?\d+(?:\,\d+)*?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)',newstr2))
            print " List %s " %  val_currency
            for i in range(len(val_currency)):
                val2 =  val_currency[i]
                remove_commas = re.compile(r',(?=\d+)*?')
                val3 = remove_commas.sub('', val2)
                print val3              

     if __name__=="__main__":main()
```

> **EDIT UDP**
>   I am able to extract the currency value but with the currency of -ve value are conflicting with date format(dd-mm-yyyy). And during extracting string value its also extracting [.|,|] how not to read these characters.

**Ouput of check_currency**:

```
>List ['5,200.33', '1,15,200.33', '5589965.26', '11520', '19', '-04', '-2013'] 
>5200.33
>115200.33
>5589965.26
>11520
>19
>-04
>-2013
```

**Expected Ouput of check_currency**:

```
>List ['5,200.33', '1,15,200.33', '5589965.26', '11520'] 
        >5200.33
        >115200.33
        >5589965.26
        >11520
```

Comment: Does your actual input contain the string `<RS|$|QR|#>`, or is it your way of expressing that you expect one of the symbols?

Comment: @JanneKarila I have edited my question. It is just notation to express any one of the currency type.

Comment: Don't use [eval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval#Security_risks) unless you know what you are _evaluating_ . Also avoid using `build-ins` that starts with double underscore (`__`) like `__len__()` . You can use `len(l2)`

Answer (score 0):

I added this `<RS|$|QR|#>\s*` at the first part of your regular expression so as
to be used as prefix for the currency value you want to match.

You can change your code to this one:

```
def check_currency(l2):
import re
for i in range(l2.__len__()):
    newstr2  = l2[i]
    val_currency = []
    val_currency.extend(re.findall(r'<RS|$|QR|#>\s*([+-]?\d+(?:\,\d+)*?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)',newstr2))
    # skip empty strings and remove comma characters
    val_currency = [v.replace(',', '') for v in val_currency if v]
    print " List %s " %  val_currency$                                                            
    for i in range(len(val_currency)):
        val2 =  val_currency[i]
        remove_commas = re.compile(r',(?=\d+)*?')
        val3 = remove_commas.sub('', val2)
        print val3
```

**Output:**

```
List ['5200.33', '115200.33', '5589965.26', '11520']
5200.33
115200.33
5589965.26
11520
```

**aditions in the code:**

```
val_currency.extend(re.findall(r'<RS|$|QR|#>\s*([+-]?\d+(?:\,\d+)*?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)',newstr2))
val_currency = [v.replace(',', '') for v in val_currency if v]
```

Comment: You might consider wrapping your alternation in some parens  =)

Comment: I have taken a screenshot! :P

Comment: @ThanasisPetsas In `check_currency(l2) ` you didn't took care of the DATE which is in the file for particular string.

Comment: @ DzKumar `check_date(l2)` works fine.. So a call of this function after `check_currency` I guess is enough.

Comment: @ThanasisPetsas: my problem was not with `check_date(l2)` my problem is with `check_currency(l2)` its also extracting date which it should not. What alteration should i do in my _REGEX_ to make it work.

Comment: Instead of writing `for i in range(len(val_currency))`, you can write `for i, currency in enumerate(val_currency)` & replace `val_currency[i]` with `currency`. `enumerate` is a simple clean way to do it. It's fast & beautiful.