# separating unspaced numbers from a string

Tags: python, math, floating-point

I am trying to evaluate arithmetic expressions, with brackets `()`.

Eg) To evaluate

```
(1.6*(2.7+(4.1/3.2)*3.9))
```

I need to separate the numbers and operators separately and I tried this:

```
def process(a,s):
    b=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
    if a in b:
          s=s*10+int(a)
          return s
    elif a==')':
          #do stuff
          return 0
    else:
          #do stuff
          return 0
a=raw_input()
s=0
for i in a:
    s=process(i,s)
```

this works fine for integers. But for float, this becomes a problem. What can i do to separate float numbers?

Comment: [What About This .. Any Solution ??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923158/extract-date-and-currency-valueseprated-by-comma-from-file)

Comment: you might be interested in sympy http://sympy.org/en/index.html

Comment: `int('(')` gives a invalid literal error. So how can that work fine for integers?

Comment: Use a regex: [How to detect a floating point number using a regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2293780/222914)

Comment: I would go backwards.  I would figure out what mathematical operators you're willing to parse, translate on those, then return the resultant string.  If there's still non-numbers, raise an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit unclear to me what your code is trying to achieve, so you may have better options available, but a neat way to parse ints in strings to `int` and floats in strings to `float` is to use `ast` module:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('1')
1
>>> ast.literal_eval('1.0')
1.0
>>> ast.literal_eval('1e10')
10000000000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Making the simplifying assumption that you don't yet want to deal with `()`s, the following code works:

```
In [62]: def process(s):
    answer = 0
    depth = 0
    decimal = False
    for char in s:
        if char == '.':
            decimal = True
            continue
        else:
            if decimal:
                depth += 1
                answer += int(char)/10.0**depth
            else:
                answer *= 10
                answer += int(char)
    return answer

In [63]: process('25.082')
Out[63]: 25.081999999999997

In [64]: process('25.0')
Out[64]: 25.0

In [65]: process('25')
Out[65]: 25
```